# How can I optimize a rational function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: rational function]

I know I need to take the derivative and set it equal to zero but what equations can I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of many kinds of optimization problems. In general, you should ask yourself, "What is the quantity I want to optimize?", and then "How can I represent this quantity mathematically?".

- **What is the quantity I want to optimize?**

  This would be the area of the triangle, and in this case the type of optimization you are seeking is minimizing its area.
- **How can I represent this quantity mathematically?**

  The area of a triangle has a well known formula, in particular for $b$ and $h$ the base and height lengths of the triangle:
  $$A = \frac{1}{2}bh$$
- **Put it in a formula of one variable.**

The base can be seen to be of length $x$, where $x$ is the point where the triangle intersects the $x$ axis. Similarly, we can see that we can create a formula for the line, namely:
$$y-2 = m(x-3)$$
for $m$ the slope of the line. At $x = 0 $, this gives you the height $h$ of your triangle, and so we can substitute this into our original equation:
$$A(x) = \frac{1}{2}x(-3m+2)$$
Keep in mind though that $m$ is a function of $x$, so you should calculate this prior to differentiating your function. This should be enough to help you finish the rest of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Write down the equation of the hypothenus. We already know a point on the hypothenus, knowing the slope $m$, would fully determine the line.
- If $m$ is fixed, we can determine the $x$ intercept and $y$-intercept in terms of $m$ and we can write the formula of the area in terms of $m$.

Comment: Hypotenuse would be $c=/sqrt{a^2+ b^2}$ right? So now what do I do? where do I plug in the point on the hypotenuse?

Comment: How can I get the x and y intercept?

Comment: can you write down the equation of the line that passes through $(3,2)$ and it has slope $m$?